# Parse \n separated json with circe

Tags: json, scala, circe

do you guys know how to parse an array of json objects but without square brackets

```json
{ "jsonValue1": "val1", "jsonValue2": [1, 1, 2, 2]}
{ "jsonValue1": "val1", "jsonValue2": [1, 1, 2, 2]}
{ "jsonValue1": "val1", "jsonValue2": [1, 1, 2, 2]}
```

to a List[MyScalaType]

```scala
case class MyScalaType(jsonValue1: String, jsonValue2: List[Int])
```

regular parsing to such List returns: error Malformed message body: Invalid JSON

Comment: That is not a valid json. You either fix it or break down into a valid json parts.

Comment: If you have that as an **fs2** `Stream` _(e.g. from a file)_ you can use this: https://github.com/circe/circe-fs2 - Another option, is to just break the input by lines and then parse each line.

Comment: @GuruStron well not a valid **JSON** yes, but a valid and common format :)

Comment: Spark also reads such json files https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html

Comment: Use [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala) to do it in the most secure, correct, and efficient way. It has [a built in support for parsing of white-space separated JSON values from `java.io.InputStream` without need to hold the whole input or parsed values in the memory](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/blob/a4b322fc7358106bdb0d8941dff2df1e96ebb8b8/jsoniter-scala-core/jvm/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/core/package.scala#L82)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, thanks to [Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%C3%ADa-su%C3%A1rez)
with "io.circe" %% "circe-fs2" i was able to parse such json

here is short overview.
i'm using http4s client

```scala
client.get(uri)(
   _.bodyText
    .through(stringStreamParser)
    .through(decoder[F, MyScalaType])
    .compile
    .toList
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you can split the string into lines and transform the string into a valid json string before parsing

```
import io.circe.{Decoder, Json}
import io.circe.parser.{decode, parse}
import io.circe.generic.semiauto

case class MyScalaType(jsonValue1: String, jsonValue2: List[Int])
object MyScalaType {
  implicit val dec: Decoder[MyScalaType] = semiauto.deriveDecoder
}

val str =
  """
    { "jsonValue1": "val1", "jsonValue2": [1, 1, 2, 2]}
    { "jsonValue1": "val1", "jsonValue2": [1, 1, 2, 2]}
    { "jsonValue1": "val1", "jsonValue2": [1, 1, 2, 2]}
  """

val lines = str.linesIterator.filter(_.trim.nonEmpty).toList

val str1 = lines.mkString("[", ",", "]")

val res = parse(str1)
res.map(_.noSpaces)
// Right([{"jsonValue1":"val1","jsonValue2":[1,1,2,2]},{"jsonValue1":"val1","jsonValue2":[1,1,2,2]},{"jsonValue1":"val1","jsonValue2":[1,1,2,2]}])
res.flatMap(_.as[List[MyScalaType]])
// Right(List(MyScalaType(val1,List(1, 1, 2, 2)), MyScalaType(val1,List(1, 1, 2, 2)), MyScalaType(val1,List(1, 1, 2, 2))))
decode[List[MyScalaType]](str1)
// Right(List(MyScalaType(val1,List(1, 1, 2, 2)), MyScalaType(val1,List(1, 1, 2, 2)), MyScalaType(val1,List(1, 1, 2, 2))))
```

Or you can split the string into lines and parse every line into json

```
import cats.syntax.traverse._

val res = lines.traverse(parse).map(Json.arr)
res.map(_.noSpaces)
// Right([{"jsonValue1":"val1","jsonValue2":[1,1,2,2]},{"jsonValue1":"val1","jsonValue2":[1,1,2,2]},{"jsonValue1":"val1","jsonValue2":[1,1,2,2]}])
res.flatMap(_.as[List[MyScalaType]])
// Right(List(MyScalaType(val1,List(1, 1, 2, 2)), MyScalaType(val1,List(1, 1, 2, 2)), MyScalaType(val1,List(1, 1, 2, 2))))
```

Comment: exactly what i did earlier, but i was looking for built in solution. Thanks anyway